# Solving a differential equation that includes cosine

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

Anyone interested in coming up with a concise equation for $u(\tau)$ given the equation for its derivative below?

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{d\tau}=-\sigma u + S\bigg(1+B\cos(\tau)\bigg)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I will assume that $\sigma, S, B$ are all constants as you've not stated otherwise.

This is a fairly simple ODE to solve as it's first order, and it's linear. Because it's linear it has a superposition principle which we can use to get the solution in the form of

\begin{equation}
u(\tau) = u_c(\tau) + u_p(\tau).
\end{equation}

Where $u_c(\tau), u_p(\tau)$ are the complementary and particular functions respectively.

To get the complementary function we solve the homogeneous equation, we can do this by *guessing* an exponential of the form: $\alpha \exp(\lambda \tau)$ (where $\alpha$ is a constant), this yields $\lambda = - \sigma$, such that
\begin{equation}
u_c(\tau) = \alpha e^{-\sigma \tau}.
\end{equation}

Now to find the particular function we *guess* $u_p(\tau) = \beta + \gamma \cos(\tau) + \varepsilon \sin(\tau)$ for $\beta, \gamma, \varepsilon$ all constants. Substituting this into the ODE gives three equations which can be solved for each of these constants. Giving the final form of the particular function as

\begin{equation}
u_p(\tau) = \frac{S}{\sigma (1 + \sigma^2)} \left[ 1 + \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 B \cos(\tau) + \sigma B \sin(\tau) \right].
\end{equation}

Now, we just add these two solutions together to give the final solution as
\begin{equation}
u(\tau) = \alpha e^{-\sigma \tau} + \frac{S}{\sigma (1 + \sigma^2)} \left[ 1 + \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 B \cos(\tau) + \sigma B \sin(\tau) \right].
\end{equation}

Comment: i worked on this in parallel to you.  my answer is identical to the answer in the paper i'm trying to replicate, except for the difference in the trigonometric expression written [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1531270/219075).  i'm trying to tell whether your answer matches mine, matches the paper, or matches neither.

Comment: I'm not really sure what it is that you are trying to achieve here? The solution I have written is the general solution to the ODE you have provided in the question.

Comment: what do you mean it's "the general solution"?  it's one form of the solution.  obviously your solution could be rearranged in all kinds of ways.  rearrangements might produce my solution or the solution in the paper.  i'm trying to replicate the solution in the paper.

Comment: there's no need, for example, to split the function into its "complementary" and "particular" functions to solve the ODE.

Comment: Do you understand what it means to have a general solution of an ODE? And I know there is "no need" to write the solution as a linear combination of these functions, however, this is the technique I've used to solve it. You can solve it using whatever technique you please! But, you will always end up getting the result that I have given (provided of course that you solve it correctly).

Comment: i don't understand what you're not understanding.  this is one statement of the solution.  it is a statement that is totally unhelpful to me.  i'm trying to solve the equation *in the way it was solved in the paper*.  you've answered my question, which is all well and good, but i'm asking you to verify whether this "general" solution implies the solution in the paper -- or whether the solution in the paper is incorrect.

Comment: i understand that this second question of mine goes beyond my original question, above.